# About Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Let's say I have $N$ balls and $N$ boxes, first, each ball should have been dropped into its corresponding box, but now if I randomly drop the balls into the boxes with replacement, which means maybe some of the boxes have more than one ball.

Let $X$ be the random variable recording the number of ball that received the correct ball, try to find the probability that only one of the balls goes into the right box, which means $P(X=1)$.

I think this should be done by a Poisson distribution, so the parameter of the distribution $\mathrm{\mu}$, i don't know how to find it.

Comment: If $X$ is Poisson-distributed, $\Pr(X=k)>0$ for $k=0,1,2,\dots$  The probability that there are more than $N$ balls in the correct box is clearly $0$, however.

Comment: Hint: There are $N$ ways to choose ball that lands in the right box, and all the other balls must land in the wrong box.  It's straightforward to compute the probability that this occurs.

Comment: is the $P=(1-\frac{1}{n})^n$?

Comment: Not quite.  The exponent should be $n-1$